# I have a F5 BigIP 1500 system with RedHat v 3.2.25. How do I change the user password?

Tags: big-ip

I have tried login as an admin and then tried

```
bigip shell
user <username> password none <newpassword>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

After you log in, just use "passwd" can change it:

```
$ passwd
Changing password for user xxx.
Changing password for xxx
(current) UNIX password:
```

Answer (score 0):

The software is NOT the RedHat. BigIP has its own OS which is based on Redhat/CentOS, but RedHat ways won't work on BIGIP. Run `version` in bpshell (or `show sys version` in tmsh) to get the actual version of the software. Also search http://ask.f5.com for info like this. (eg. SOL3350).

Given the platform, it would likely be either v9.x.x or v10.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

you can use TMSH command to change the password:
tmsh modify auth user  password